# StaggeredGridLayoutManager: Adding Margin makes the layout items pushed to the side

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

So, I'm working on a small project and I wanted to add `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`to the file. While it works if I don't add an `itemDecorator` and no `margin` or `padding` in my layouts. As soon as I add margins it pushes the list to one side. I'm attaching a screenshot to clarify the issue.[image]

---

---

Here is my Code:

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new EqualSpaceItemDecoration(8));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And the Layout File for the item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/wallpaper_item_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/wallpaper_item_image"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've looked around for some time and am not able to find something that fixes the issues. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if you've already found the solution, but I'll leave the comment in case anyone else sees the question.

I was able to solve this problem by doing the following:

```
layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
```

Example:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);          
layoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually did not solve it and went on for some alternative designs. But now that I know how to fix it. I can actually give a layout option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin use:

```
viewManager.gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE
```