# Recyclerview elements with StaggeredGridLayoutManager are loading inverted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to load a list with recyclerview, StaggeredGridLayoutManager and sections, however when I scroll to scroll through the list, sometimes some elements of it are loaded inverted. Here is the picture of the problem. I would like all elements of the list to be loaded from left to right. Does anyone have any suggestions to force this on a recyclerView?

[image]

Instantiate recyclerview

```
productsAdapter = ProductsAdapter(
            onItemSelected = { product, haveAnySelected ->
                if (haveAnySelected)
                    openPaymentMethods()
                cartProductsAdapter.updateList(productsAdapter.selectedProducts)
                calculateTotalValue()
            },
            onItemDeselected = { product, haveAnySelected ->
                if (!haveAnySelected)
                    closePaymentMethods()
                cartProductsAdapter.updateList(productsAdapter.selectedProducts)
                calculateTotalValue()
            }
        )
rv_products.adapter = productsAdapter
val layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
rv_products.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

My adapter

```
class ProductsAdapter(
    list: List<Product> = listOf(),
    val onItemSelected: (Product, Boolean) -> Unit,
    val onItemDeselected: (Product, Boolean) -> Unit
): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        const val PRODUCT_TYPE = 1
        const val HEADER_TYPE = 2
    }
    var products: MutableList<Product> = list.toMutableList()
    private var filteredProducts: MutableList<Product> = mutableListOf()
    private var favoriteProducts: MutableList<Product> = mutableListOf()
    var selectedProducts: MutableMap<Product, Int> = mutableMapOf()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        if (viewType == PRODUCT_TYPE)
            ProductViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.products_adapter_item,
                parent,
                false
            ))
        else // HEADER_TYPE
            HeaderViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.products_adapter_header,
                parent,
                false
            ))

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int =
        filteredProducts[position].name?.let {
            PRODUCT_TYPE
        } ?: run {
            HEADER_TYPE
        }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = filteredProducts.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = filteredProducts[position]
        if (getItemViewType(position) == PRODUCT_TYPE) {
            (holder as ProductViewHolder).bindView(
                item,
                position,
                onSelected = { prod, pos ->
                    if (selectedProducts.contains(prod))
                        selectedProducts[prod] = selectedProducts[prod]!! + 1
                    else
                        selectedProducts[prod] = 1
                    notifyItemsChanged(prod, position)
                    onItemSelected(prod, haveAnySelected())
                },
                onDeleted = { prod, pos ->
                    selectedProducts.remove(prod)
                    notifyItemsChanged(prod, position)
                    onItemDeselected(prod, haveAnySelected())
                }
            )
        } else { //HeaderType
            (holder as HeaderViewHolder).bindView(item.category)
        }
    }

    private fun notifyItemsChanged(prod: Product, position: Int) {
        if (prod.isFavorite) {
            val favoritePosition =
                filteredProducts.indexOfFirst { it.name != null && it.id == prod.id }
            val itemPosition =
                filteredProducts.indexOfLast { it.name != null && it.id == prod.id }
            notifyItemChanged(favoritePosition)
            notifyItemChanged(itemPosition)
        } else
            notifyItemChanged(position)
    }

    private fun updateCategories() {
        removeAllCategoriesFromList()
        if (filteredProducts.isNotEmpty()) {
            var lastItem = filteredProducts.first()
            filteredProducts.add(0, Product(category = lastItem.category))
            val iterator = filteredProducts.listIterator()
            favoriteProducts = mutableListOf()
            for (product in iterator) {
                if (lastItem.category != product.category) {
                    iterator.previous()
                    iterator.add(Product(category = product.category))
                    iterator.next()
                }
                lastItem = product
                if (product.isFavorite) {
                    favoriteProducts.add(product)
                }
            }
            if (favoriteProducts.isNotEmpty()) {
                favoriteProducts.add(0, Product(category = "Favoritos"))
                filteredProducts.addAll(0, favoriteProducts)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun removeAllCategoriesFromList() {
        val listCategory = products.filter { it.name == null }
        listCategory.forEach {
            products.remove(it)
        }
    }

    fun getPositionCategory(category: Category) = filteredProducts
        .indexOfFirst { it.category == category.name && it.name == null}

    fun updateList(list: List<Product>) {
        products = list.toMutableList()
        filteredProducts = list.sortedWith(compareBy({it.category}, {it.name})).toMutableList()
        updateCategories()
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun clearSelected() {
        selectedProducts.clear()
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun haveAnySelected(): Boolean {
        selectedProducts.forEach { (_, amount) ->
            if (amount > 0) return true
        }
        return false
    }

    fun searchItem(word: String) {
        filteredProducts = if (word.isEmpty())
            products
        else
            products.filter {
                it.name?.toLowerCase()?.unaccent()?.contains(word.unaccent()) ?: false
            }.toMutableList()
        filteredProducts = filteredProducts.sortedWith(compareBy({it.category}, {it.name})).toMutableList()
        updateCategories()
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun getProductCategory(position: Int): String {
        val product = filteredProducts[position]
        return if (product.id == null || !product.isFavorite)
            product.category
        else {
            val indexFirst = filteredProducts.indexOfFirst { it.id == product.id }
            if (indexFirst == position)
                "Favoritos"
            else
                product.category
        }
    }

    fun updateListFromCart(list: MutableList<Pair<Product, Int>>) {
        selectedProducts = list.toMap().toMutableMap()
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    /** ViewHolder **/

    inner class ProductViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        fun bindView(
            product: Product,
            position: Int,
            onSelected: (Product, Int) -> Unit,
            onDeleted: (Product, Int) -> Unit
        ) {
            itemView.run {
                tv_name.text = product.name
                tv_value.text = "${context.getString(R.string.currency)}${product.value?.asDecimal()}"
                itemView.setOnClickListener { onSelected(product, position) }
                Glide.with(context)
                    .load(product.imageUrl)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_image_broken)
                    .into(iv_image)
                ib_delete.setOnClickListener { onDeleted(product, position) }
                if (selectedProducts.containsKey(product)) {
                    tv_amount.text = String.format("%02d", selectedProducts[product])
                    setupViewSelected(this)
                } else
                    setupViewNotSelected(this)
            }
        }

        private fun setupViewNotSelected(view: View) {
            view.run {
                cv_root.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bg_card_product_unselected)
                cv_root.cardElevation = convertDpToPx(context, 4).toFloat()
                tv_amount.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                ib_delete.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }

        private fun setupViewSelected(view: View) {
            view.run {
                cv_root.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bg_card_product_selected)
                cv_root.cardElevation = convertDpToPx(context, 4).toFloat()
                tv_amount.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                ib_delete.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

    }

    inner class HeaderViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindView(secionName: String) {
            val layoutParams = itemView.layoutParams as StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
            layoutParams.isFullSpan = true
            itemView.tv_section_title.text = secionName
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You want us to help with your code, without your code? Post your code here first. Also, Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53871713/8244632) out, it will help I believe.

Comment: I edited the post and added some code for reference

Comment: Have you looked at the link I had provided?

Comment: Yes, I did it, but the problem persists. I still haven't figured out what it can be.